# Which one is rarer? Netherite or Emeralds?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I've been playing Minecraft for years and I have yet to find an emerald. On my newest world, I was trying to find netherite in the Nether. I was mining on Y coordinate 12 using TNT and beds. I had a stack of TNT and laid each piece 2 blocks apart. When I blew it up, all I found was more netherrack, gold ore, and quartz.

Acknowledge that I created a giant tunnel and still didn't find any netherite. Then again, I've never found an emerald, ever. I've also only found one piece of ancient debris, ever.

(I might just be unlucky.)
So, which one is rarer? And what are the chances of finding it?

Comment: Please don't answer in comments.

Answer (score 3):

Emeralds spawn in veins of 1 in each chunk only in extreme hills. While 2 ancient debris spawn per chunk, but although they usually don't spawn together. If you're thinking by quantity then emeralds are more rare.